# ¿Cual evento uso para detectar cada entrada en un Qlineedit de PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

comunidad... Necesito detectar cada entrada de un Qlineedit y que cada vez que reciba un valor que ejecute un metodo de mi clase, por ejemplo:

En mi **init**

```
tcompra = self.ui.tcompra.text()
```

En mi otro metodo que quiero ejecutar:

```
def spread(self):
    try:
        # Tasa de compra
        tcompra = int(self.ui.tcompra.text())
        # Tasa de venta
        tventa = int(self.ui.tventa.text())

        self.ui.spread.setText(str(tventa - tcompra))

    except ValueError:
        self.ui.spread.setText("")
        self.ui.tcompra.setText("")
        self.ui.tventa.setText("")
```

Lo que quiero es que en mi `__init__` pueda detectar cada entrada de mi variable **tcompra** y que ejecute siempre el método **spread**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres detectar el cambio de texto mostrado en el QLineEdit entonces debes usar la señal `textChanged`:

```
self.ui.tcompra.textChanged.connect(self.spread)
```

Comment: Te re mamaste, funciono fino (Y)

Comment: @Abdiel te recomiendo leer la docs de Qt ya que hubieras tenido la solucion en menos de 1 minuto: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#textChanged